# Get number of iterations until convergence in R's RSNNS package

Tags: r, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I want to fit a recurrent neural network in `R`by using the `RSNNS`package. The package provides the option to set the number of maximum iterations, as done in the sample code below by `maxit = 1000`. Is it possible to see how many iterations the algorithm used until convergence?

```
library(RSNNS)
library(xts)

#Load Lynx data
data(lynx)

#Scale data and convert to xts
data  <- as.xts((lynx - min(lynx)) / (max(lynx) - min(lynx)))

#Build xts object with 5 lags to analyze
lags <- 5
for(i in 1:lags){

  feat <- lag(lynx, i)
  data <- merge(data, feat, all = FALSE)

}

#Get features and target
features <- data[,-1]
target   <- data[,1]

#Fit network
rnn      <- elman(features, target, maxit = 1000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it runs the maxit number of iterations by default. When you run the below, the iteration continues even after plateauing in the graph.

```
rnn <- elman(features, target, maxit = 1000)
plotIterativeError(rnn)

#then run this
rnn <- elman(features, target, maxit = 10000)
plotIterativeError(rnn)
```

You can probably use `head(which(abs(diff(rnn$IterativeFitError)) < 1e-20), 1)` to find the iteration step when it converges.

Comment: Is there a way to make the function stop if an error criterion is met?

Comment: If I remember correctly it calls the Internal C code. You can print the function in the console and check it. If it does you will need to change the C code and re compile it.